# Problem in Extracting Named Entity in RASA 3.1

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

I'm trying to extract the name from the user intent using spacy entity model in RASA 3.1. Not getting the entity name. Some One please help me out to fix this issue.

Hi All, I’m very new to RASA and struck with Entity Extraction for getting the username.Please someone help me out to solve this issue.

Please provide me documentation for references.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.